# python,tkinter,canvasで動く折れ線グラフ（モニタ画面）を作れるでしょうか？

Tags: python, tkinter

pythonとtkinterを使ってＧＵＩのプログラムを書いています。
canvas内に静止した折れ線グラフを表示しました。
センサからの情報で折れ線グラフが動く、モニタ画面を作りたいのですが、matlibplotを使わず、canvasだけでやるのは無理でしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

この記事の応用で可能だと思われます。
[Live Plot in Python GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15736393/9014308)

回答記事に示されたスクリプトは Python 2.x系のようでしたが、回答に付いたコメントにあるように最初の`import Tkinter as tk`を`import tkinter as tk`と`Tkinter`の大文字/小文字を変更しただけで Python 3.x系 で動作するようになりました。
回答での入力データは乱数でシミュレートしているようです。

確認環境は Windows10 64bit Python 3.9.1 です。

Comment: 回答ありがとうごさいます。リンク先のサンプルプログラムを確認しました。canvas.coordsでモニタ画面が作れそうです。これをベースにコーディングしようと思います。